# Which one is better using $_POST directly in plugin file or using admin-ajax.php to receive data from ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Usually all WORDPRESS developers uses `admin-ajax.php` for receiving data from `ajax` in their plugin .
But also it is possible to add query vars and receive posted data directly in main plugin file , and then saving that in a global variable.
This way we can receive posted data in an easier way.  but is it safe ? and why all uses `admin-ajax.php` in their plugin ?

Comment: In fact, I do not use wordpress. I think you can use $ _POST, in this case, be sure to reload the page. `header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

Answer (score 0):

`admin-ajax.php` is part of the WordPress AJAX API, and yes, it does handle requests from both backend and front. Try not to worry about the fact that it is in wp-admin. I think that is a strange place for it too, but it is not a security problem in itself.